# Firebase and Mysql usage together

Tags: mysql, firebase

I am trying to create a messaging app. I am using firebase to store my messages like this

toId: "4"
message: "hello"
fromId: "5"

My users however are stored in a mysql database so how can I join between the two in realtime so I can access the users's name and profile picture from my mysql database using the toId and fromId in firebase?

Thanks

Comment: The answer is purely dependent on your use case. I would suggest storing that data in Firebase so it's available online from any device. You may want to consider going with one or the other or elaborate on your use case so we can formulate an appropriate answer. In the mean time please take some time and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am having similar issue please see here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60584283/combine-firebase-and-mysql-query-results

Answer (score 1):

You can use GUUIDs to generate unique keys independent of database generated auto keys. Using this you can access both to MySql and Firebase.
You can also read something about Domain Driven Development and Event Sourcing.